# How to have authenticated jenkins xml api while accessing using Resttemplate?

Tags: java, spring, rest, jenkins, resttemplate

I am using jenkins xml api for my application. I need to access a particular xml api of Jenkins to view jobs on it, But it requires password. How could I authenticate the session?

Comment: Are your app access Jenkins as a service provider or are you using as a lib?

Answer (score 0):

Use [CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory.html) as the underlying client factory, and call the jenkins authentication method using the same client factory. Authentication cookies will be stored in the underlying client and hence be available to your RestTemplate calls.

Comment: I will sugest something like that. Nice answer.

Comment: tried that. But didnt work out. Not able to use Preemptive auth, as couldn't able to find a way of adding BasicHttpContext in the rest api call.

Comment: this thread outlines similar usage: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?69573-Basic-Authentication-with-RestTemplate